# How to make two arrays contiguous so that Numba can speed up np.dot()

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numba, dot-product

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

Nx = 15
Ny = 1000

v = np.ones((Nx,Ny))
v = np.reshape(v,(Nx*Ny))
A = np.random.rand(Nx*Ny,Nx*Ny,5)
B = np.random.rand(Nx*Ny,Nx*Ny,5)
C = np.random.rand(Nx*Ny,5)
   
@jit(nopython=True)
def dotplus(B, v, C):
    return np.dot(B, v) + C

k = 2
D = dotplus(B[:,:,k], v, C[:,k])
```

I get the following warning, which I guess refers to arrays `B[:,:,k]` and `v`:

```
NumbaPerformanceWarning: np.dot() is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 2d, A), array(float64, 1d, C))
  return np.dot(B, v0) + C
```

Is there a way to make the two arrays contiguous, so that Numba can speed up the code?

PS in case you're wondering about the meaning of `k`, note this is just a MRE. In the actual code, `dotplus` is called multiple times inside a `for` loop for different values of `k` (so, different slices of `B` and `C`). The `for` loop updates the values of `v`, but `B` and `C` don't change.

Comment: I would guess you'd have to rearrange the data in `B` and `C` such that `k` is in the *first* index, i.e. you can call `B[k, :, :]` and `C[k, :]`.

Comment: If the arrays are non-contiguous Numba just uses a naive implementation. To create a contiguous array, where BLAS algorithms will be used you can use `np.ascontiguousarray()`. This will lead to a full copy, which isn't beneficial in your matrix-vector product, but will be beneficial if you have a larger matrix-matrix product. So the best you can do is to rearrange your data as flawr already mentioned.

Comment: I expect Numba to slow down in your scenario. `np.dot` runs mostly in C++ code, `+` is mostly C++ as well. Numba works best when you have lasting loops, not a single invocation with just two operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Flawr is correct. `B[..., k]` returns a `np.view()` into `B`, but does not actually copy any data. In memory, two neighbouring elements of the view have a distance of `B.strides[1]`, which evaluates to `B.shape[-1]*B.itemsize` and is greater than `B.itemsize`. Consequentially, your array is not contiguous.

The best optimization is to vectorize the `dotplus` loop and write

```py
D = np.tensordot(B, v, axes=(1, 0)) + C
```

The second best optimization is to refactor and let the batch dimension be the first dimension of the array. This can be done on top of the above vectorization and is generally advisable. It would look something like

```py
A = np.random.rand(5, Nx*Ny,Nx*Ny)
# rather than
A = np.random.rand(Nx*Ny,Nx*Ny,5)
```

If you can't refactor the code, you need to start profiling. You can easily swap axes temporarily via

```py
B = np.moveaxis(B, -1, 0)
some_op(B[k, ...], ...)
B = np.moveaxis(B, 0, -1)
```

Contrary to max9111's comment, this will not net you anything compared to `np.ascontiguousarray()` because the data has to be copied in both cases. That said, a copy is `O(Nx*Ny*k)` + buffer allocation. Direct matrix-vector multiplication is `O(Nx*Ny)`, but you have to gather the elements first, which is really expensive. It comes down to your specific architecture and concrete problem, so profiling is the way to go.

Comment: great answer! Before I accept, just a clarification: I can refactor (to a certain extent) so I can implement both the `np.tensordot` and the `A = np.random.rand(5, Nx*Ny,Nx*Ny)` (whose gains are cumulative, IIUC). So I don't need to profile, or to do `moveaxis`. Right?

Comment: @DeltaIV Correct, you will not have to use `moveaxis`. Storing the batch-axis first and using a single library call should be the fastest option indeed. Also, keep in mind that you will have to reorder the axes along which to compute the `np.tensordot` if you reorder your arrays.