# How to setup a batched matrix multiplication in Numba with np.dot() using contiguous arrays

Tags: numpy, optimization, numba, contiguous

I am trying to speed up a batched matrix multiplication problem with numba, but it keeps telling me that it's faster with contiguous code.

Note: I'm using numba version 0.55.1, and numpy version 1.21.5

Here's the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def numbaFastMatMult(mat,vec):
    result = np.zeros_like(vec)
    for n in nb.prange(vec.shape[0]):
        result[n,:] = np.dot(vec[n,:], mat[n,:,:])
    return result

D,N = 10,1000
mat = np.random.normal(0,1,(N,D,D))
vec = np.random.normal(0,1,(N,D))

result = numbaFastMatMult(mat,vec)
print(mat.data.contiguous)
print(vec.data.contiguous)
print(mat[n,:,:].data.contiguous)
print(vec[n,:].data.contiguous)
```

clearly all the relevant data is contiguous (run the above code snippet and see the results of print()...

But, when I run this code, I get the following warning:

```
NumbaPerformanceWarning: np.dot() is faster on contiguous arrays, called on (array(float64, 1d, C), array(float64, 2d, A))
  result[n,:] = np.dot(vec[n,:], mat[n,:,:])
```

2 Extra comments:

1. This is just a toy problem for replication. I'm actually using something with many more data points, so hoping this will speed up.
2. I think the "right" way to solve this is with np.tensordot. However, I want to understand what's going on for future reference. For example, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784563/how-to-make-two-arrays-contiguous-so-that-numba-can-speed-up-np-dot) addresses a similar issue, but as far as I can tell, doesn't address why the warning shows up directly.

I've tried adding a decorator:

```
nb.float64[:,::1](nb.float64[:,:,::1],nb.float64[:,::1]),
```

I've tried reordering the arrays so the batch index is first (n in the above code)
I've tried printing whether the "mat" variable is contiguous from inside the function

Comment: Since this could be a BUG for a specific version of Numba please add the version you are using. For such small matrices, smaller than around (20x20), it could also make sense to avoid a dot call at all. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356461/4045774

Comment: Updated (it's numba version 0.55.1). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave this up, but I figured it out:

Outside of a numba function:

```
mat[n,:,:].data.contiguous==True
```

but inside numba, `mat[n,:,:]` is no longer continous.

Changing my code above to `np.dot(vec[n], mat[n])` removed the warning.

I'm making this the "correct" answer since it solved my problem. However, according to max9111's response, this behavior may be a bug!